# how to fix 'fatal: cannot use C:/Users/Administrator/ as an exclude file' error in gitbash?

Tags: git

While I try to use add command `git add .` the git bash shows me this 
`fatal: cannot use C:/Users/Administrator/ as an exclude file error.`

how can I fix this problem?

Comment: `git config core.excludesfile`

Comment: after putting this command... git is showing this- 'C:/Users/Administrator/' it just showing the directory. but my problem still occurs.

Comment: It was not a fix, just a hint where the problem is — in configuration file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look where the wrong setting is — in the local config or in the global:

```
git config core.excludesfile
git config --global core.excludesfile
```

and remove the bad setting:

```
git config [--global] --unset core.excludesfile
```