# How can i fix git init problem not working

Tags: git, git-for-windows

[image]

i alredy use git init

[image]

My file not become green and I can not do anything about git. It always said i need permission

[image]

Image below is what i want that i capture from youtuber:Zinglecode

[image]

pleas help. I'm very new.This is my first website and i never learn anything about code before.

I need the way to fix this problem.

why its become like this.

Comment: Please include *code*, not *images of code*: see [*Why not upload images of code errors when asking a question*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question). [edit] the question and include code fragments with the *code sample* button (`{}`).

Comment: As @WillemVanOnsem says, please don't use images... paste the exact commands you are using, and the exact answers as text.  Something is wrong with the command, but we cannot see this.

Answer (score 2):

It's very difficult to understand what is going on, from the images I assume there is a wrong setting which tries to use the folder C:/Users/User as an exclude file. As mentioned in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57449898/12904316) try to look where the wrong setting is:

```
git config core.excludesfile
git config --global core.excludesfile
```

and then modify it.